# Changing Opencart Affiliate Variable Name from Tracking to Ref?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I'm working on an opencart website, and I was asked if it was possible to change the current affiliate link from reading `mywebsite.com/currentproduct?tracking=tracking-code-here`
to `mywebsite.com/currentproduct?ref=tracking-code-here`.

So pretty much the variable named to read `?ref=tracking-code` instead of `?tracking=tracking-code-here`

My guess is I would just change the the GET varible name from `tracking` to `ref`. However, Im not sure exactly where that is.

I found this code in the `admin/model/customer/customer.php` and was wondering if the part that reads `tracking = '" . $this->db->escape($data['tracking']) . "',` could just be changed to `ref` without breaking something important.

```
    if ($data['affiliate']) {
        $this->db->query("REPLACE INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_affiliate SET customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "', company = '" . $this->db->escape($data['company']) . "', website = '" . $this->db->escape($data['website']) . "', tracking = '" . $this->db->escape($data['tracking']) . "', commission = '" . (float)$data['commission'] . "', tax = '" . $this->db->escape($data['tax']) . "', payment = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment']) . "', cheque = '" . $this->db->escape($data['cheque']) . "', paypal = '" . $this->db->escape($data['paypal']) . "', bank_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['bank_name']) . "', bank_branch_number = '" . $this->db->escape($data['bank_branch_number']) . "', bank_swift_code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['bank_swift_code']) . "', bank_account_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['bank_account_name']) . "', bank_account_number = '" . $this->db->escape($data['bank_account_number']) . "', status = '" . (int)$data['affiliate'] . "', date_added = NOW()");
    }       
}
```

I haven't coded in opencart for almost 5 years, and it's, unfortunately, starting to show. Any answer to this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to edit this in the OC code, you can look at the file `/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php`

Around line 126:

```
// Tracking Code
if (isset($this->request->get['tracking'])) {
    setcookie('tracking', $this->request->get['tracking'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 1000, '/');

    $this->db->query("UPDATE `" . DB_PREFIX . "marketing` SET clicks = (clicks + 1) WHERE code = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->get['tracking']) . "'");
}
```

You can see that it's looking for the value set by the `GET` parameter `tracking` which seems to be what you're looking to change.

Fortunately it seems like OC relies on the cookie thereafter so you shouldn't have to worry about it anywhere else but testing will determine whether that is the case or not

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use .htaccess rewrite rule to rename URL parameter. here is the best solution for this

[htaccess change url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366468/htaccess-change-url-parameter)